# Silverstripe $Children.Filter

Tags: filtering, e-commerce, parent-child, silverstripe, children

I'm working on an eCommerce solution using Silverstripe and the Silvershop module. I'm wanting to display all products in the top level of my shop page, broken down into categories (TShirts, Hats, Programmes...). At the moment I'm getting the induvidual 'ProductCategories' but each category is display a list of ALL Children pages ('Products') and not the relevant children for each category.

The filter I am using is set up as below:

```
<% loop $Children.Filter('ClassName', 'ProductCategory') %>
```

Can anybody offer advise as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like.

**PHP**

```
function ProductCategoryList() {
  return ProductCategory::get();
}
```

**Template**

```
<% if $ProductCategoryList %>
  <% loop $ProductCategoryList %>
    <h2>$Title</h2>
    <% loop $ProductsShowable %>
      <div class="product">
        <h3>$Title</h3>
        <div>$Content</div>
      </div>
    <% end_loop %>
  <% end_loop %>
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gavin. I've put the PHP code on productcategory.php and set up SS template as follows:

Comment: unfortunately this drops all products from the page! I'm hoping that I've set this up correctly?
    <ul class="productList $ClassName col_12 first" style="list-style: none;">
    <% if $ProductCategoryList %>
    <% loop $ProductCategoryList %>
    <h2>$Title</h2>
    <% loop $ProductsShowable %>
    <div class="product">
    <h3>$Title</h3>
    <div>$Content</div>
    </div>
    <% end_loop %>
    <% end_loop %>
    <% end_if %>
    </ul>